# Magento: simple jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, magento

I have a magento theme that makes use of jQuery and it runs without any issues.
The problem arises when i try to add some more jQuery files to be used by my custom html code that i have added on every page.

I added my jQuery files in the `head.phtml` (Located at: 
`app/design/frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/page/html/head.phtml`)

THIS IS THE ADDITON I MADE TO MY `head.phtml` FILE (using the method [suggested here](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/using-jquery-magento)):

```
<!-- adding jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
//]]>
    </script>

<!-- ************* -->
```

The jQuery files that I am trying to use are:

1. [jquery.cookie.js](http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cookie.js)
2. [jquery.cycle.all.latest.js](http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js)
3. [jquery.min.js](http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.min.js)

Now, I get following errors in my chrome console:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` for
  `jquery.cookie.js`, line 72.
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` for
  `jquery.cycle.all.latest.js`,line 10.
- `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$s' of object [object Window] is not a
  function` for this line : `$s(document).ready(function(){....}` in
  my custom html code that i am trying to include on every page.

ON THE OTHER HAND:

[Here is](http://boozzr.com/testing321/js/lof_slider/jquery.easing.js) an example of jquery file that is being used by my theme and it runs without any problem.

Comment: Please don't include "Though I reckon, this is a fairly basic issue/error, ... Would really appreciate some help! :)" in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import scripts which make use of jQuery after importing jQuery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamapag. But I am sorry, I didn't understand exactly what you are implying. Can you explain further.

Comment: You inserting sripts that use jQuery lib before it was inserted, you shoult change order of insertion your scripts. First should be `jquery.min.js`, then others. Sorry for my bad english.